# How to add a vertical thick line border to the entire column after every merged cell heading at the top?

Tags: excel, vba, border

Here is how I want it to have appeared? Please suggest a VBA code for this

[image]

```
Sub FormatTest()
    With Sheets("Test")
        With .Range("$B:$Z")
            .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=mod(row(),2)=0"
            With .FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but was unable to modify it for the vertical border. It is beyond my VBA knowledge

Sub FormatTest()

With Sheets("Test")

    With .Range("$B:$Z")
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=mod(row(),2)=0"
        With .FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
          .LineStyle = xlContinuous
          .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .TintAndShade = 0
          .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End With
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code in it. Comment is not the place for you to dump codes. @Raj

Comment: I do not have the access to edit my question as I have just joined Stackoverflow

I have tried this VBA but it is only adding vertical border to the cell only and not the entire column and also skipping the very last column

here is the screenshot



https://i.imgur.com/RM778L8.png

Comment: Using merged cells is not advisable. The code you've posted does not seem to relate to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work based on your screenshot. As remarked above, merged cells are generally problematic and should be avoided wherever possible.

```
Sub FormatTest()

Dim c As Long, r As Range

With Sheets("Test")
    For c = 1 To .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set r = .Cells(1, c).MergeArea
        With Union(.Cells(1, c), .Columns(r(r.Columns.Count).Column))
            With .Borders(xlRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
        End With
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working exactly as I wanted. I have a very basic knowledge of VBA and I usually record macros in the excel sheet to complete some of my repetitive tasks.